# MongoCollection.find() does search twice?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-collection

I am using the code snupped as below :

```
if (collection.find(toFind) != null) {
            dataFound = collection.find(toFind).first();
        } else {
            System.err.println("NULL");
        }
```

As collection.find() is being called twice here, will that be performing 2 searches on database or becasue it returns a FindIterable, its just a cusror???

We are restricted to limit the database operations and avoid as much necessary, as we are paying it per request unit

Comment: Why do you need that null check in the first place? Wouldn't find always return a result, even if it is empty?

Comment: YES - FindIterableImpl will return a result..even if its empty.
I can modify my check like  - 
`if (collection.find(toFind).count() > 0) {
            dataFound = collection.find(toFind).first();
        } else {
            System.err.println("EMPTY");
        }`

but still the question remain, whether the .find() will be called twice ??

i would expect it would return a cursor and the cursor will not close until a further operation like first(), sort(), filter(), etc are called

Does that clarify my original question?

Any documentation around that

Answer (score 3):

Why not store the find result and then use the store variable

```
var queryResult = collection.find(toFind)
if(queryResult != null){
 dataFound = queryResult.first()
} else { // Handle error here}
```

Or better yet just use the findOne method to get the first result

```
var queryResult = collection.findOne(toFind)
if(!queryResult){
  //Handle result here
}
```

And to answer the question, yes it will perform the query twice.